# Long loading time on mobile WebGL causing browser crash/freeze, Three.js JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, webgl

I am loading a large JSON model using Three.js's JSONLoader. It seems to work fine on most devices however on a few it crashes the browser.

So my question is:
Is there a way, using Three.js's JSONLoader to allow an update to be called in the middle of downloading a file so the browser doesn't freeze/crash, or is there a way to give it a timeout call to stop it from causing problems?

Comment: You can take a look at the three.js example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_scene which has a progress bar so it must be doing something similar to what you want.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I have been busy with other projects. I took a look at the code of that you linked @gaitat however, It appears that it keeps track of the quantity loaded not the  % of each Item loaded. After further research I believe that THREE.js does not have the functionality that I am looking for. Thank you for you're assistance however.